# Spell checking user's input by aspell, but how to invoke the INTERACTIVE mode in this context?

Tags: shell-script, shell, zsh, aspell

I have wrote a script which receives a user's sentence,
i'd like to pipe the string to **aspell** and then get the ***INTERACTIVE*** screen's suggestions (in case user had some typos). Afterwards the words would be sent back to the script and I'd replace the typos with the corresponding words.

I'm aware of aspell options:

1) Check the file for typos and display a list of suggestions **in interactive mode**:

```
aspell check <file name>
```

2) Check the file for typos and display a list of suggestions **not in interactive mode**:

```
cat <filename> | aspell -a
```

but if I try option one, I get **"Error: Stdin not a terminal."**,
I'll be glad to get any fruitful tip how to overcome this issue? :)

Thank you

Comment: For option 1, maybe creating a file descriptor for  `/dev/tty` (which always is yr terminal) in a manner proposed by @John1024 at https://superuser.com/questions/834502/possible-to-get-a-bash-script-to-accept-input-from-terminal-if-its-stdin-has-bee .... or opt for the non-interactive mode, where you would get  suggestions displayed, accept or modify each of them and then submit those corrections from within yr script....

Comment: @Cbhihe thank you for the assistance, I wrote:
`exec < /dev/tty`

it worked like a charm! :)

Comment: You should write a complete answer to your own question and then accept it, so others may benefit from it  in the future, taking stock of the fact that your questions has an accepted answer. (In doing so you will not accrue karma points, but you will be doing a service to the community by enriching the database.)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can't get away without using a temporary file. `zsh` has builtin support for that with its `=(...)` form of command substitution.

Here, to spell-check the content of a variable (of the output of `printf %s $string`):

```
{
  (){
    aspell check -x $1 >&3 3>&-
    cat $1
  } =(printf %s $string) | IFS= read -rd '' corrected_string
} 3>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, which worked for me:

```
TMP_FILE=`mktemp`

echo "${USER_INPUT}" > "${TMP_FILE}"

# Allows me to read user input below, assigns stdin to keyboard
exec < /dev/tty

# I'm assuming you have a aspell (spell checker) installed on your system
# invoke aspell and check for typos
/usr/bin/aspell check "${TMP_FILE}"

ANSWER=$(cat $TMP_FILE )

if [[ "${ANSWER}" != "${USER_INPUT}" ]]; then
    echo "After applying fixes: ${ANSWER}"
fi
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Note that using `echo` means input that contains backslashes (or things like `-nene`) will be mangled (hence the use of `printf` in my answer). Using command substitution means the tailing empty lines will be removed (hence the use of `read` in my answer). Note that without `-x`, `aspell` will leave a backup file behind. You'll also need to handle the clean-up  of that tempfile (handled automatically by `=(...)`).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a 1-line shell script which I called dict:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo $* | aspell pipe
```

> dict  charitible
>   @(#) International Ispell Version 3.1.20 (but really Aspell 0.60.7-20110707)
>   & charitible 8 0: charitable, charitably, heritable, veritable, writable, credible, shareable, irritable